# Repeating the content of a numpy array arbitrarily

Tags: python, numpy

I am dealing with `numpy` arrays of shape `(nb, 128, 128, 3)` where nb is a variable quantity. I am looking for a way to concatenate them.

An example input: Two numpy arrays with shapes `(1088, 128, 128, 3)` and `(823, 128, 128, 3)`.

Now, the shape of the output array after the desired operation should be `(1911, 128, 128, 3)`.

**Note**: The number of numpy arrays to be concatenated could be variable.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: [`concatenate`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Comment: Might be a bit expensive !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have variable no. of arrays in a list, there also `np.concatenate` does the trick.

```
listOfArrays = [a, b, c,.... ,n]
np.concatenate(listOfArrays, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```py
import numpy as np

# your arrays
A = np.array(...)
B = np.array(...)

C = np.concatenate((A, B))
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But what if instead of having two numpy arrays I have n?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, agree.

Comment: @S.P The tuple argument of concatenate can be of length n.